# Постоянный токен vk api

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте!

Вот пишу приложение, работающее с vk api, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что нужно сделать в приложении авторизацию с получением токена (пока просто подставляю уже готовый токен).

Собственно вопрос:
Обычно токены действуют 24 часа, после чего их снова надо менять. А можно ли получить токен на более продолжительный срок, чтобы не было необходимости каждый день делать новую авторизацию? По крайней мере другие приложения, работающие с vk api не требуют ежедневной авторизации, а где-то хранят данные об авторизации. Как это организовано?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В права доступа нужно добавить "offline" при получении токена для приложения и тогда, как говорит документация VKapi, "возможен доступ к API в любое время со стороннего сервера и токен является бессрочным "

Answer (score 0):

Для получения неограниченного по времени токена достаточно при авторизации добавить в scope значение offline.

Пример:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id={ID приложения}&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=notifications,offline&response_type=token&v=5.52
```